# how to wrap a c library with opaque pointers in c++ binding

Tags: c++, c

I'm looking at wrapping some c libraries in c++ and I'm not sure what is the best way to wrap opaque pointers.

When the C-structure is part of the public API

```
typedef struct _SomeType
{
    int a;
    int b;
} SomeType_t;
```

Where there are several "member" functions:

```
void SomeTypeFoo( SomeType_t* obj, ... );
void SomeTypeBar( SomeType_t* obj, ... );
```

I like the approach of deriving from the base to simply associate these "member" functions as actual class members. i.e.:

```
class SomeTypeWrapper:
    public SomeType_t
{
    void foo( ... );
    void bar( ... );
};
```

As far as my understanding goes, I believe that `SomeTypeWrapper` is "binary compatable" with `struct _SomeType` such that `SomeTypeWrapper*` can be casted to`SomeType_t*` so that the c++ method implementation might be:

```
SomeTypeWrapper::foo( ... )
{
    SomeTypeFoo( (SomeType_t*)this, ... );
}
```

See Note[1].

However, in some libraries they like to keep the definition of the structure private (I suppose this is to allow changes to the implementation without changing the headers/API ). So in the headers I have something like this:

```
typedef struct _SomeType SomeType_t;
```

And then all of the "member" functions deal with these opaque pointers. In order to "wrap" these methods into an interface, what I've done so far is to provide a class which contains the pointer.

```
class SomeTypeWrapper
{
    private:
        SomeType_t* m_data;

    public:
        SomeTypeWrapper( SomeType_t* data ): m_data(data){}
        void foo(...);
        void bar(...);
};
```

This means that for any function in the c library which returns such an opaque pointer, I have to allocate a new object to carry that pointer around. For a lot of libraries that is probably fine but this design complicates implementing the wrapper and for speedy c-libraries that do a lot of small-object allocation, I suspect that this extra object over-head can lead to a significant performance penalty. In addition, the underlying object may be reference counted so in some cases I have to make decisions about whether SomeWrapperType increases the reference count, implements a copy constructor, has a private constructor, etc.

In most cases I'm happy to pay that penalty for the nicer interface, but I'm looking for other options. Is there a cleaner way of dealing with opaque c-pointers in a c++ wrapper library? Related: is there a good way to implement wrapper classes so that the c++ headers don't have to include the c-library headers AND doesn't require wrapper object allocation?

Note[1]: I believe this cast is safe as long as the same compiler is used and `SomeTypeWrapper` adds no additional members and has no virtual methods. By same compiler, I'm assuming the c-library compiled by gcc will work with the c++ wrapper compiled by the same gcc. Perhaps that is not guaranteed ?

Comment: If you do it right, the C++ interface won't interact publicly with any `SomeType_t` at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your final version of `SomeTypeWrapper` (in the question) is the way to go forward.

> This means that for any function in the c library which returns such an opaque pointer, I have to allocate a new object to carry that pointer around. For a lot of libraries that is probably fine but this design complicates implementing the wrapper and for speedy c-libraries that do a lot of small-object allocation, I suspect that this extra object over-head can lead to a significant performance penalty.

There is no overhead. An instance of a `class` with one data member and no `virtual` methods is no bigger than its sole member. If you define the methods inline in the header, there'll be no function call overhead either. So, as long as you don't allocate these instances with `new`, but on the stack:

```
SomeTypeWrapper some_object(make_some_object());  // one allocation on the heap
```

then you have a zero-overhead solution.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using 'new' when you need it.  A stack-based object will be freed when its stack frame goes out of scope, which is not always desirable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: the point is that it leads to double indirection and opens up the possibility of memory leaks when the `new` fails. When the object must survive its scope, it should get a copy or move constructor. (Using smart pointers to the underlying C object is an even better idea, though.)

Comment: You've convinced me. I see how copying the object should be exactly as expensive as copying the original pointer, so you get the nice interface for free. I've continued following this path and so far haven't run into too many problems with it... other than the weirdness of thinking of these objects as pointers. I'm considering naming the classes "SomeTypePtr" to make it clear that they are just shuffling around the pointer with it's methods attached.

Comment: @cheshirekow: that's leaking implementation details. I never call C class wrappers `*Ptr`; I expect `->` to be required for member access on a pointer. If you want pointer-like access, prefer smart pointers with custom destructors. (Oh and btw., make these objects noncopyable if at all possible. That saves a lot of trouble.)

Comment: Well, I feel like thats exactly what my wrapper objects are... smart pointers. At least when the underlying object is reference counted, then the destructor calls the c-function to decrease the reference count. Likewise, the copy and assignment operators will increase the reference count. But I guess you're right, it is leaking implementation details.

Comment: @cheshirekow: if you have reference counts then there's no problem. But they aren't pointers in the C++ sense until you add `operator*` and friends. I believe it was in Stroustrup's own textbook that a wrapper for `FILE*` is discussed, appropriately called just `File`, not `FilePtr`.

Comment: That is a very good point. That reminds, me I should go skim through that book again...

Answer (score 3):

If you are *wrapping* your opaque pointer, you can surely not *derive* from it.  A seemingly attractive method to get some functionality for free, it soon gets messy when you use inheritance where aggregation is intended: your wrapper *is not one of the library's objects*, instead, it... *wraps a library object*.

If you treat your wrapper object with the same care as you would treat the library object, there is always one wrapper (at most) for each opaque pointer.  You can share your wrapper objects with e.g. a `unique_ptr` (C++11 has them!).  This is a good thing, considering that the wrapped object is a valuable resource.

Speaking of shared pointers, they can take a `deleter` function as constructor argument:

```
struct Wrapper : boost::non_copyable 
{
private:
   std::unique_ptr<SomeType> wrapped;
public:
   Wrapper()
   :wrapped(SomeType_create(), &SomeType_destroy)
   // upon destruction of wrapped, use SomeType_destroy
   {
   }

   void foo() { SomeType_foo(wrapped.get()); }
   int bar(int i) { return SomeType_bar(wrapped.get(),i); }
};
```

Yes: you will need a method wrapper for each member function in the `SomeType`; that's completely normal since C++ uses a different calling convention than C and you're bound to replace each C-style member-function with a C++ one.

And you have to take care that you create exactly one wrapper per library object; this object is under your control, and you can share it with whoever you trust with it, but it will be just one object.

Comment: unique_ptr is nice, but I'm finding that more often then not the user-code doesn't get ownership of the object (and so doesn't have destroy-rights). So I'm not sure this is particularly useful here.

Also, when you say that "your wrapper is not one of the library's objects, instead, it... wraps a library object." I wouldn't necessarily take that for granted... but I do see how it is probably a better philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, what you propose above is an ugly hack that can lead to all kinds of woes. It is OK to cast up (and down, when it makes sense) the inheritance hierarchy but it is undefined when casting from pointer to wrapper class to the pointer to the object pointed to by the first member). There is absolutely no guarantee that the address of the first member will be aligned with your wrapper address.

In my opinion, you are trying to solve a wrong problem here. Maybe creating a C++ wrapper for each and every kind of small C "objects" in not the right strategy? Why not having a library that wraps the *functionality* of the underlying C library instead of wrapping the *individual objects*? And when it does it, it manages the underlying C objects in a meaningful, parsimonious way (i.e. by employing RIAA, shared pointers etc.)

Comment: Yeah, it probably is an ugly hack. As a kind of academic note, what about using reinterpret_cast? Isn't it guaranteed that the casting `SomeType_t* --> SomeTypeWrapper* --> SomeType_t*` results in the original pointer?